# Digits count method

Tags: java

I created a method that should count digits of numbers but it is only working when the the first digit is not zero.
For example it  gives for the number 01011100 the result 7 instead of 8, and for the number 00101111 6 instead of 8.
I am very thankful for any help!.

```java
public static int countDigits(int x) {
    int y=0;
    while (!(x== 0)) 
        {
        x /= 10;
        y ++;
        }

    return y;
}
```

The method starts counting digits only after the firs "1" comes.

Comment: `!(x == 0)` is an awfully verbose way to write `x != 0`.

Comment: Off-topic:`countDigits (x)` should give the same result as `(int)(Math.ceil(Math.log10((double) Math.abs(x))))`.

Comment: How about if you change the code: `public static int countDigits (int x, int minDigits) ... return Math.max (y, minDigits); }`

Comment: Chris> Thank you for your advice, I will edit the condition.

Comment: Old Dog Programmer> actually I wanted to creat my own Digits counting method, but in the worst case I will just use your recommended method above.                                                  Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 4):

`00101111` isn't a thing that an `int` value can represent. Literally. Something like:

```
int x = Integer.parseInt("00101111");
int y = Integer.parseInt("101111");
```

x and y are bit for bit identical. It is **impossible** to tell the difference between `x` and `y` here. There is in fact no possible way to store, say, 400000000000 in an `int` (it doesn't go that far; ints can store any integral number between -2^31 and +2^31-1). There also is no way to store specifically `00101111` either. That is what makes `int` so efficient, they can only represent very specific things. And `00101111` isn't one of them. Only `101111` is.

If you have a need to store such a concept, well, that isn't a number. It's some sort of limited string; use `String` (in which case you can just invoke `str.length()` to figure out how many characters are in it), or write your own type for it.

If you are provided an `int` value and asked to count the digits, and you want an answer of '8' because that int was created with `00101111`, that is **completely impossible** - you'll need to change whatever code gave you that `int`, and change it to give you a `String` or some specific other data type instead.

Comment: Thank you really for your useful explaination I got it know, I will try changing the Data type to String it might work then.